# How to share data exclusively between a directive and a factory in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angularjs-service, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to build a modal directive with an Async API to open the modal.
What I was thinking about is a factory that returns me the API object that manipulates the modal directive. Using Angular-UI Bootstrap 0.6.0 I wanted something like so:

```
Module.factory("ModalAPI", function ($modal) 
    var ModalAPI;

    ModalAPI.confirm = function (title, text, buttons) {
        // Set up a confirmation modal
        return $modal.open(options).result;
    };

    return ModalAPI;
});
```

So far so good. Now to set up the modal I would something like:

```
Module.factory("ModalAPI", function ($modal) 
    var ModalAPI,
        Modal;

    Modal = {};

    ModalAPI.contents = function () {
        return Modal;
    }

    ModalAPI.confirm = function (title, text, buttons) {
        Modal.title = title;
        Modal.text = text;
        Modal.buttons = processButtons(buttons);

        return $modal.open(options).result;
    };

    return ModalAPI;
});
Module.directive("modal", function(ModalAPI) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.modal = ModalAPI.contents();
        },
        template: "<div class='modal-header'>" +
                  "    <h2>modal.title</h2>" +
                  "</div>" +
                  "<div class='modal-body'>" +
                  "    <h2>modal.text</h2>" +
                  "</div>" +
                  "<div class='modal-footer'>" +
                  "    <button ng-click='$close(button.result)' ng-repeat='button in buttons'>{{button.label}}</button>" +
                  "</div>"
    };
});
```

The problem is how to set up the modal sharing the `Modal` object only with the directive and no one else?

Answer (score 0):

The directive definition object allows you to define a controller for the directive.  From [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> controller - Controller constructor function. The controller is
>   instantiated before the pre-linking phase and it is shared with other
>   directives (see require attribute). This allows the directives to
>   communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior. The
>   controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the
>   following locals:
>
> $scope - Current scope associated with the element
>
> $element - Current element
>
> $attrs - Current attributes object for the element
>
> $transclude- A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope: function(cloneLinkingFn).

The controller on a directive behaves just like a controller for an ng-view.  I think it's just what you are looking for.